# Graalvm not detecting nodejs

Tags: java, node.js, graalvm

New to graalvm. Trying to run a node module in Intellij

```
        Context c = Context.create("nodejs");

        try {
            File birdJS = new File(PATH);
            c.eval(Source.newBuilder("nodejs", birdJS).build());
            Value testFunction = c.getBindings("nodejs").getMember("test");
            String testResult = testFunction.execute().asString();
            System.out.println(testResult);
            Value callAPIFunction = c.getBindings("nodejs").getMember("callAPI");
            String callAPIresult = callAPIFunction.execute().asString();
            System.out.println(callAPIresult);

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but im getting this error (stack trace below):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A language with id 'nodejs' is not installed. Installed languages are: [js].
    at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineException.illegalArgument(PolyglotEngineException.java:131)
    at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineImpl.throwNotInstalled(PolyglotEngineImpl.java:1109)
    at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineImpl.requirePublicLanguage(PolyglotEngineImpl.java:1116)
    at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.requirePublicLanguage(PolyglotContextImpl.java:1491)
    at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.lookupLanguageContext(PolyglotContextImpl.java:1453)
    at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.eval(PolyglotContextImpl.java:1462)
    at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextDispatch.eval(PolyglotContextDispatch.java:63)
    at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:399)
```

Before I changed it from a JavaScript file to a node module the code ran and returned as expected

Node is definitely installed in graalvm, I can interact with it on the command line and when I check using gu list its there (version 22.3.1) along with js

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; Creating a Context to execute node.js is not supported. You can execute plain JavaScript, but not node.js.

==

You are making a category error here. Let me explain.

As stated in the Context javadoc (https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Context.html)

> A polyglot context represents the global runtime state of all installed and permitted **languages**.

Node.js is not a language. As stated on https://nodejs.org/en/

> Node.js® is an open-source, cross-platform JavaScript **runtime environment**

It's an environment for executing JavaScript. GraalVM supports node.js as an environment for executing the GraalVM JavaScript Engine. When you install GraalVM node.js as you did, you can run

```
$GRAALVM_HOME/bin/nodejs -e 'console.log(1+1)'
```

And it will happily work. This is because the nodejs executable here is a **runtimne enviroment**  for JavaScript which knows, for example, how to talk to your terminal when you tell it to `console.log`. But if you are running in your JVM application (which is a runtime itself and knows how to talk to your terminal as per our example) creating a Context to execute node.js does not make sense since node.js wants to talk to the terminal directly but in this case it would have to talk to the JVM since it's the one that talks to the terminal. This is a silly example but it illustrates the point I think.

What you can do though, interestingly, is run your node.js application on GraalVM, call into some Java code that creates a Context with e.g. `ruby` as the language and execute ruby code inside Java code inside the node.js code. This works because the Context API was intentionally designed to be **embeddeable** into other applications and runtimes. This is **not true** for node.js.

Finally, to sum up - you cannot create a Context for executing node.js, because Contexts are for **languages** and node.js is a **runtime environment**

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that "nodejs" is not installed in the environment.
Try using

```
Context c = Context.create("js");
```

Comment: nodejs is installed, that's the problem here

Comment: Did you set the PATH?

Comment: yeah PATH is set